# Convert HTML Time into Java Time Object

Tags: java, datetime

I am getting startTime and endTime value from html5 input type. I am getting it in Servlet in String.

**I want to convert it into Java Date Object so I can use methods like before and after for comparing Time.**

```
    String startTimeValue = request.getParameter("startTime");
    String endTimeValue = request.getParameter("endTime");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    Date startTime = sdf.parse(startTimeValue);
    Date endTime = sdf.parse(endTimeValue);
    sdf.format(startTime);
    sdf.format(endTime);
    System.out.println(endTime.before(startTime));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're able to do the parsing right this way :

```
String DateString = request.getParameter("date");
//SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(myDateString);
        
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
calendar.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to the given date 
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute; /... similar methods for minutes and seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I am achieving it using the following Code Snippet

```
    String startTimeValue = request.getParameter("startTime");
    String endTimeValue = request.getParameter("endTime");

    String[] time1 = startTimeValue.split(":");
    Date date1 = new Date();
    date1.setHours(Integer.parseInt(time1[0]));
    date1.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(time1[1]));
    date1.setSeconds(0);
    String[] time2 = endTimeValue.split(":");
    Date date2 = new Date();
    date2.setHours(Integer.parseInt(time2[0]));
    date2.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(time2[1]));
    date2.setSeconds(0);

    System.out.println(date2.after(date1));
```

Comment: WARNING: those methods are **deprecated** since Java 1.1 (1997).

Comment: @BalusC : Currently I am achieving what I want using this Deprecated Method. I will update the code whenever I get to know about it.